# What file types can a chromebook run?

Tags: filesystems, metadata, chromebook, google-chrome-os

Considering that on my school chromebook, (.exe, .targz, .rar, etc) file types cannot be run, i want to know what filetypes the apps are from in the playstore, since i do not have direct access to view the file properties of the apps. I'm guessing .APK, still unsure.

Comment: The playstore and android use APK files.

Comment: If you are looking for executables, then the Chromebook can not run any if it is a school Chromebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All APK files, which includes playstore apps.
Microsoft Office files: .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt (read-only), .pptx
Media: .3gp, .avi, .mov, .mp4, .m4v, .m4a, .mp3, .mkv, .ogv, .ogm, .ogg, .oga, .webm, .wav.
Images: .bmp, .gif, .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .webp.
Compressed files: .zip, .rar.
Other: .txt, .pdf.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer is good.